# How to watch or download periscope live streams from start?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, live, youtube-dl, periscope

I am trying to figure how watch/download a periscope livestream from it's starting point. The app doesn't let go back more than 2 minutes so I tried downloading as someone told me it downloads from beginning but it didn't. It started from the current time.

I tried running :

```
youtube-dl https://www.pscp.tv/w/b_7KWDFyYVFaeFhCTXhaanp8MXluS09Sd05QRFZ4Uuj5klcOLvuiNqQPC2PcorcMlZOwD3uZyIP7o-UXVYNi
```

I get

```
https://prod-fastly-ap-south-1.video.periscope.tv/Transcoding/v1/-/chunk_1563350917969725824_36817_a.ts?type=live

https://prod-fastly-ap-south-1.video.periscope.tv/Transcoding/v1/-/chunk_1563350926386273572_36818_a.ts?type=live
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it’s not possible to watch a Periscope live stream from the beginning, unless someone has shared it to a group from the beginning. However, it is possible to download a live stream from the beginning, and in fact, that’s what our app [Snagscope](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iqtecture.app.snagscope) does, if you enable Trackback in settings.

The way it works is you have to download two different streams. One is the live stream, and the other is the replay stream up until that point. Periscope uses Wowza with HLS streams. To get the playlist URL for the HLS stream you can call the Periscope REST API. The folks at Pmmlabs have done a nice job of publishing an unofficial version of this API here:

https://static.pmmlabs.ru/OpenPeriscope

To get the live stream, you just need to call GET accessVideoPublic with the broadcast id, and to get the replay portion of a live stream you call the same endpoint with replay_redirect set to false, and latest_replay_playlist set to true. Once you have all the segments from both playlists, merge them all together and you have your broadcast from beginning to end.